# positioning scalable image on top of other image

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I have a project I am working on where I want to position one image on top of another image.  I have been able to figure out how to do this but as soon as I attempt to center the image and make it scalable it will no longer display the way I want it.

I want the yellow image (banner) to display on top of the main picture (top-pic).  I want the banner to be centered relative to the top-pic with a 60px margin from the bottom of the top-pic.  Does anyone know how to position it like this while allowing both pictures to be scalable?

[My JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/austin350s10/7wry4w0p/)

[Updated JSFiddle but still not working](http://jsfiddle.net/austin350s10/7wry4w0p/11/)

My CSS:

```
.top-pic img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 35%;
  width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}

.banner-wrap {
  width: 100%;  
  position: absolute;
}

.banner {
  width: 796px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

.banner img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 59px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<section>
  <div align="center" style="background-color:#EAC40D;">
    <div class="top-pic">
      <div>
        <img src="http://www.affordablehomecare.org/Templates/assets/images/slider/1.jpg">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="banner-wrap">
    <div class="banner">
      <img class="banner" src="assets/images/banner_title_home.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [first fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/austin350s10/7wry4w0p/), you're styling an `img` based on a `banner` class:

```
.banner img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 59px;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

However, you have no element with that class, so the style is ignored.

Change it to this:

```
.banner-wrap img {
  ...
}
```

Absolute-positioned elements are relative to any positioned parents, or the `body` element if no parents are positioned.  In your first fiddle, the image's parent is *not* positioned.  You can remedy that like this:

```
.banner-wrap {
  position: relative;
}
```

Finally, having `width` and `height` set to auto prevents your image from being scalable.  Leave `height` as auto, but change `width` to a percentage:

```
.banner img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 59px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Your images should now both be scalable.

### Fiddle

Comment: You're a scholar or a god!  Thank you so much.  You have no idea how long I have been working on this problem.  Also, thanks for the education.  Always something to learn!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the wrapper div, and use only img element.

```
<section>
    <div align="center" style="background-color:#EAC40D;">
        <div class="top-pic">
            <div><img src="http://www.affordablehomecare.org/Templates/assets/images/slider/1.jpg"></div>                
        </div>
        <img src="http://www.affordablehomecare.org/Templates/assets/images/banner_title_home.png">
    </div>         
</section>
```

and use this css:

```
.top-pic img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height:35%;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */}
 img{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:59px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;}
```

I have modified your JSFiddle to make it work. It's here:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/7wry4w0p/5/
```

Comment: Thanks Nelson but it didn't work for me on the full project.  As soon as I add text below the position is off again.  Also, the banner image is not scaling.  I updated my JSFiddle. Any ideas?

Comment: it's just a position problem. Take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/vfvwxvt3/ I just added left, bottom and width in some places.

Comment: Still seems as if it's stuck in one spot.  When you change the window size the banner does not stay centered inside the top-pic

Comment: that's because it uses absolute positioning. I though that's what you want. Change to relative and see how it goes.

Comment: Still a no go.  This is why I put it on this site.  Been pulling my hair out all day trying to make it work with no luck....

Comment: So check out this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/austin350s10/7wry4w0p/11/  It seems to be the closest I can get but the banner image still will not scale.  Any ideas?